# What errors can happen when (Windows) system file cache disk write-back fails? how are they reported?

Tags: windows, winapi

Apparently the Windows file cache flushes data to disk asynchronously, even when using the synchronous WriteFile() API. Quoting ["File Caching" on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364218%28v=vs.85%29.aspx):

> By default, [...] write operations write file data to the system 
>   file cache rather than to the disk, and this type of cache is 
>   referred to as a write-back cache.

Assuming that write-through and no-buffering flags are *not* used, what happens if the actual write to disk fails? Can clients be notified of such failures? What is the expected client error handling model for such failures? "Fire and forget" and "Write and pray" come to mind but maybe there is something else.

Secondary question: are there certain classes of errors that are guaranteed to be detected early? E.g. will WriteFile() always return an error if the disk is full? -- even though the actual write to disk would be deferred?

I would like to know how to write reliable file i/o that responds to these kinds of errors without disabling the Windows File Cache.

Bonus points: is this handled differently on other operating systems? Can you recommend a good resource on the topic?

Comment: The client can have closed the file handle and exited before the actual write-to-disk even occurs, so it stands to reason that there is no feedback to the client available in this situation. It's handled at a lower level.

Comment: Even *with* the write-through and no-buffering flags set, the disk can lie about whether it has actually committed the data to disk; it can still be in the buffer cache on the disk itself (or on the RAID controller).

Comment: @EricBrown yes there was an [interesting link regarding that](http://disruptivesql.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/sata-and-write-through/) posted to the MSDN page I mentioned. My question is about errors and error reporting at the Windows level however. Presumably lying disks have quite high confidence about their ability to eventually commit the data to disk (power outages aside). Not sure how the OS could make such assumptions.

Comment: Yet another question that can be easily answered by just trying this.  Open the case and pull the cable.

Comment: @HansPassant I'm looking for an exhaustive answer of *all* failure modes, not just "what happens when the cable is pulled". Disk full is another possible one maybe. For the specific case of disk removed I was thinking of using a USB thumb drive.

Comment: In extension to my previous comment: presumably there are other ways in which the system file cache can fail. I have no way to "try" those failure modes since I don't know what they are. Empiricism is not a substitute for formal behavioral specification.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Windows 7, the user is notified via a pop-up dialog from the notification area.

Normal errors (such as the disk being full, lack of permissions, etc.) are reported back to the application immediately, these do not cause late failures.

Late failures can only happen in a handful of situations, such as a hardware failure or operating system crash.  They can also happen when writing to a network share if the connection drops unexpectedly for any reason.

In most cases, it doesn't make sense for an application to worry about this.  Data loss is to be expected under these circumstances; let the user deal with it.

If the data you are writing is unusually important, then you may need to worry, in which case you will have to use the write-through and/or no-buffering flags.

There is no third option.

Comment: Thanks Harry this is a very helpful and clear answer. Can I ask how you know this info? Is it documented somewhere?

Comment: Experience.  Windows, unfortunately, is far from fully documented; arguably, given its size and complexity, it would be impossible to do so, certainly it would be unaffordable.  On the other hand, Microsoft go to quite extreme measures to ensure compatibility with any widely-depended-upon behaviour, so (as unsatisfactory as it may be from a computer science standpoint) the practical approach to answering this sort of question is to ask instead "what does everyone else do?"

Comment: (A basic understanding of what the OS components are and how they interact helps; i.e., knowing that NTFS lies on top of the cache, in combination with knowing the general structure of an NTFS volume, makes it clear that caching can't hide a disk full condition.)